# How can i prevent default tooltips to be shown hovering on svg elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, tooltip

I'm trying to show an interactive SVG image drawn in a HTML page. 
I'm not experienced with javascript/jQuery language, but using some jQuery plugins like PowerTip I'm currently able to show customized tooltips when hovering on SVG elements. 
Customized tooltips appear, but disappear after a second, when they're closed by the appearance of default tooltip (in all browsers), showing so just the content of "title" element.
Is there a way to disable default tooltips?
Below is what I do to show my customized tooltips with PowerTip.

```
$('#myGraph .node').on({ powerTipPreRender: function() {
    var title = "";
    $('a text', this).each( function(i) {
        title += " " + $(this).text();
    });

    var synonyms = "";
    $("synonym", this).each( function(i) {
        synonyms += "<li>" + parseSynonym($(this).text()) + "</li>";
    });
    $(this).data('powertipjq', $([
           '<p><b>' + title + '</b></p>',
           '<p><b>Synonym(s)</b><ul>' + synonyms + '</ul></p>'
           ].join('\n')));
}});
```

Tnaks in advance

Comment: Tooltip plugins disable default tooltips. The fact that your PowerTip tooltip disappears indicates a problem there. Solve that and the default tooltips will not appear.

Comment: @isherwood: I thought the same, but this morning I kept the powertip example (working perfectly) and when I replaced the text content of a div with a simple svg, loaded by a php include call, the trooble appeared again: when I hover on the element, it appears the powertip tooltip, then it is closed by the appearance of default tooltip (showing the title of the svg element which I hover).

Comment: I already tried to replace "title" tag, to prevent default tooltips. Now Powertip tooltips appear and disappear quickly, even if default tooltips don't appear. 
This happens just on SVG elements.

Comment: It appears I'm incorrect, then. Sorry, I have no ideas for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried a lot of solutions, from renaming the "title" tag to setting the tooltip as an empty string. 
At the end, I understood that's not possible to prevent showing the default svg tooltips.

Comment: It is in fact possible by inserting an empty `title` tag at the beginning of your SVG. I added an answer below to highlight this solution.

Comment: `<g class="tick" opacity="1">
    <text>Getting ...</text>
    <title>Getting there</title>
</g>`

after removed title , default tooltip can be ignored and added customised tooltip

Answer (score 27):

**Short answser:**

```
.no-tooltips {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

---

**Detailed answer:**

You can disable the tooltips by removing all the actions from the mouse. Add it on the child that displays the tooltip. But beware, it also disables any text selection from the mouse.

*Example:*

```css
.no-tooltips {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g>
    <title>Tooltips</title>
    <text x="0" y="0" font-size="10" dy="0">
      <tspan x="0" dy=".8em">Tooltipsable</tspan>
      <tspan x="0" dy=".8em" class="no-tooltips">Not tooltipsable</tspan>
    </text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 21):

```
svg {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

In my case.

I have

```
<a title="click me plz" >
   <svg>
    <title> hello title <title>
    <g>gggggrrrrrrrr.....</a>
   </svg>
</a>
```

CSS

```
a > svg { pointer-events: none; }
```

Answer (score 7):

Removing the title tag from SVG will remove the tooltips from appearing.

Answer (score 4):

As [Girish Sadanandan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4812972/girish-sadanandan) already said - you can remove `title` elements altogether and tooltips will disappear. You can do this if you want to retain `pointer-events` functionality but get rid of tooltips. If you don't need events on that specific element then using CSS attribute `pointer-events: none;` is a 'cleaner' way to go.

Here my JavaScript code sample :

```
var title_elements = Array.from(my_svg_document.querySelectorAll("title"));

title_elements.forEach(function(el) {
    el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
});
```

Edit: Since it's not so obvious how to get a reference to an `svg` document:

```
my_svg_document = document.getElementById('my_svg_id').contentDocument;
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't name the attribute as `title` call it something like `message` or `output` that will do the trick.

**EXAMPLE**

Instead of:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tooltip" title="Hi this is a tooltip.">
<i class="fa fa-question-circle" aria-hidden="true">
</i>
</a>
```

Use:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tooltip" message="Hi this is a tooltip.">
<i class="fa fa-question-circle" aria-hidden="true">
</i>
</a>
```

And at last but not least important, apply your desired format as it follows:

```
.tooltip:hover:after {
  content: attr(message);
  position: absolute;
  background:#fff;
  border:#000 solid 1px;
  color:#000;
  font-weight:300 !important;
  padding:10px;
}
```

Or in any way you want.

And goodbye default browser tooltips!

https://jsfiddle.net/1vsd5dxp/

Answer (score 1):

You can define / generate an empty `title` to hide the other one.
This solution does **not disable mouse events**.

```html
<svg height="100" width="100">
  <title></title>
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="grey"/>
  <title>never show this title</title>
</svg>
```